# How to get a gyroscope for Pokémon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

My ar is not working.
People say you can only use AR mode when you have a gyroscope
How do I get that?

Comment: it has to be built into your phone. if yours does not have one you can only get one by buying a new phone. [Here's an old list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347143/which-android-phones-out-there-do-have-a-gyroscope), anything newer than those *should* also work.

Answer (score 5):

A gyroscope is something that your phone has (or does not, depending on the model) when it is manufactured -- it is not something that can be added-on at a later date. If your current phone does not have a gyroscope, there isn't anything you can do to "get one" other than getting a new phone.